# [Spark-Structured-Streaming][Spark-Driver][How-to] Spark driver fine grained control plan for streaming query

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue, spark-structured-streaming

I am working on creating a Spark Driver fine grained control plan to maintain/operate multiple streaming query in a Spark application. We have a data source system with thousands of tables (up to 2000 tables) that go through a sourcing and standardized process before being transformed and delivered to the LakeHouse. The transformed data processes are used to deliver the same table as the source to one of two destinations in the Lake House - Kafka/Kinesis or S3, with table formats of Hudi/Delta lake.

The issue we face is that we cannot create 2000 Spark applications to ETL the data into the LakeHouse. We only have five clusters and the 2000 tables have varying SLA data freshness requirements, ranging from real-time to T-1. We want to use the Spark structured streaming to unify the Spark API.

To address this issue, we want to create a Spark Driver fine grained control plan client that will receive command control plan master and create new streaming queries on the fly, submitting them to the Spark Session. The control plan client will make it easy to operate start/stop/add-new streaming queries, so that we can better utilize our hardware resources.

I would like to have an open discussion with the community to ensure that I am on the right track with this idea, as it is quite new and unconventional. Thank you for your help.